# count in nested v-for in vueJS

Tags: javascript, for-loop, vuejs2

Im working with vueJS and the v-for seems very powerless for a simple counting. I have code similar to this

```
<template v-for="(data, id, i) in group">
   <div v-for="column in group[id]">
     <div v-for="(promo, j) in column.array" :style="{top: i*column.array.length+j}"></div>
   </div>
 </template>
```

Column.array is different for each column. i.e 23, 45, 12

I need the counting to happen like 0, 1, 2, 3...23, 24, 25 ... 68, 69, 70 ... 80

But now its happening like 0, 1, 2, 3...23, 1, 2, 3, ... 45, 2, 3 ... 12

I need this to increment css top value for each block. I have tried using a data field like height and incremented it using height++. But it is giving infinite loop error. I read in the docs mutable data shouldn't be handled that way. So how can this be accomplished?

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/wostex/j0xvba89/ . `v-for` gives index as a second argument, not third.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided some sample data.